# c#: Single handler for multiple events using same variables: best practices

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

consider the next code. it is ad hoc one time solution (lot of logic skipped and the code itself simplified), but while i was writing it, i came up with a few questions.

it retrieves files from uri, and if there is and error when retrieving from folder 'j', it stops trying to retrieve from this folder further.

as i understand, this code is not thread safe? though it looks like it works fine for me, but out of curiosity and self education (as i have little experience with multithreading), i want to figure out once and for all:

1. are `openedConnections` and `failed` (there are actually `Remove`s are present too) variables are under threat of data racing or something?
2. if it is not thread safe, what is the best practices of making it safe? where to add `lock`s and so on?
3. is there any kind of inconsistency, if those variables were not present? i mean, is it good to add `DownloadDataCompleted` handler to several events?
4. is there some benefit of making `DownloadDataCompleted` a non-static member of some dedicated class and writing `webClient.DownloadDataCompleted += new Dedicated().DownloadDataCompleted;`?
5. in general, your opinion: what is the best way to solve this kind of task? not considering small code optimizations, but conceptionally (or must i write 'conceptually'? o_O)

```cs
public class SomeClass
{
    static HashSet<int> failed = new HashSet<int>();
    static int openedConnections = 0;

    static void DownloadDataCompleted(object sender, DownloadDataCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        openedConnections--;
        if (e.Error != null)
        {
            failed.Add(MyToken(e.UserState).j);
            return;
        }
        //save data
    }

    public void Retrieve()
    {   
        for (int i = 1; i < 10000; i++)
        for (int j = 1; j < 10000; j++)
        {
            if(failed.Contains(j)) continue; 
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            webClient.DownloadDataCompleted += DownloadDataCompleted;

            var uri = string.Format("someuri/{1}/{0}", i, j);
            webClient.DownloadDataAsync(new Uri(uri+".jpg"), /*token here*/);
            openedConnestions++;

            while (openedConnections > 32)Thread.Sleep(111);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 5 questions in one post is generally too broad for SO (expected one). Side note: "best practices" and "static variables" in same sentence is something ... unusual.

Comment: Also "best practices" type of questions might be more on-topic on Programmers than SO

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov i agree, i changed topic. obviously, one can easily dispose of static variables without much effort. they are used in ad hoc solution and also serve the sake of briefness (i wouldn't do that in real-life application)

Comment: @zloidooraque Still 5 questions in one is obviously not a proper [SO] way as AlexeyLevenkov has already mentioned. You should consider concentrating on one topic at a time. And some of your questions can actually be a better fit for Programmers or CodeReview. Just don't ask about best practices on programmers - [they are no less off-topic there than they are here](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6491).

Comment: @EugenePodskal 1 and 2 are connected and cold be merged, i could remove 3 and 4 that i asked out of curiosity, but there is already an answer. they are on-topic, tho, and if i only was smart to abstain of giving numbers to questions and ask them 'unformatted', no one would complaint lol. i could change question 5 'what are the best practices' to 'how would i do in real-life application' and no one would complaint. technically this all doesn't change anything. i think you are 'overbureaucratizing' here, sorry. i will wait if Blindy will answer my edits and delete question later

Comment: @zloidooraque  Well, some words and lists actually turn on the "overzealous moderation mode" in people, but that doesn't mean that trying to soothe it by cleverly gaming the system will allow you to avoid the same close(down)-vote. It will usually increase a life-time of the question, but hardly do anything more. And I honestly don't want to find in the future some long mix of partial answers to different questions, only one of which is what I am interested in. I want to find a specific answer(s) to a specific question. And as far as I know current guidelines agree with me on that.

Comment: @EugenePodskal that makes sense! i am completely agree on second part (SRP FTW!). is it acceptable to post several questions that differ by like 10% of text (same code snippet/description, just different question)? i'm not talking here about this exact post (i still think no sense to split it), ofc. and on first part: 'prolong a lifetime' alittle was enough for me. clearly this post is weak for SO. i just _almost didn't know_ about Programmers and never used it for some reason. everything i search always leads me to SO. now i've became smarter!

Comment: @zloidooraque There is nothing wrong if you ask different questions(one question per post) about the same code. Just make sure that they are really different questions and, possibly, mention that you have already asked  question about this code but from **completely** different point of view. And, [please, use uppercase `I`](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/172/is-it-alright-to-use-lowercase-i-or-should-you-always-use-i-uppercase) in your replies, because lowercase `i` may turn out some potential answerers. And because it is just grammatically incorrect to write so in English.

Comment: @EugenePodskal  it is historically so, that I (ok) use caps only if it serves disambiguation (or for abbreviations). also with the font on SO, `I` looks te same as `l` and it just adds ambiguity. one must guess what is it I or l (heh) out of context. yes, brain does it automatically, but it doesn't change the fact. but remark about averting answerers is true, unfortunately. people are so vulnerable. comment on linked page mentions, that people are accustomed to paragraphs. looks like concern about what 'people are accustomed to' is not so big for SO team: one can't split comment to paragraphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Of course.
2. `lock()` the lists themselves before every access (`Add` and `Remove`).
3. I don't really get the question. Is it ok to have the same handler for different events? Sure who cares, it's just code. Is this specific handler good? Not really, nor is your entire architecture, down to the TCP level. This is just not how Windows is designed to work with TCP connections.
4. Well if you get paid by the line of code, sure. That's how enterprise applications get written. Even better if you get paid by memory or CPU cycles wasted.
5. *Conceptually*, the traditional way of writing web crawlers is to spawn a number of threads (the number is defined by your system, how many connections it can handle), push your download URLs into an array (don't forget `lock`), and inside the handlers pop one URL from the array (again don't forget `lock`) and download it synchronously. When you're out of items simply return (or if you're dynamically adding items wait until you get more).

Comment: 2. stupid question: do i lock openedConnections too? 3. yeah. i just was confused by the fact that method is static and for some stupid reason (m.b. 30 hours no sleep lol) was thinking smth may go bad. and how is windows designed to work with tcp connections? i'm doing almost the same you describe in 5 (next comment about it). 4. so no practical reasons? thanks.

Comment: 5. that's what i do, actually! yes, number of threads/connections is magic number (but i already said that solution is one-time and even not so, i'd omit those details for brevity) and yes, no array of urls, but hacky-looking `Thread.Sleep()`. but technically it's all the same: threads are spawned by `DownloadDataAsync` and i am sure, inside that threads download is synchronious lol. does it make any difference if i'm not spawning threads myself, but let the `WebClient` do that?

Comment: If you're talking about the thread pool, it's a lot more shallow than you could be using. Specifically you're doing it the other way around, you're looping over the array of URLs once and relying on external support for threads -- when you know it's not bound by your number of CPU cores.

Comment: DownloadDataAsync is allocating threads from thread pool. no reasons to think it's doing it in a manner, that is not the same as manuall allocating threads from ThreadPool class. but instead of using ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads i just use while `(openedConnections > 32)Thread.Sleep(111);`. i even assume, DownloadDataAsync may be handling it's thread pool interactions well enough. actually, while doing some searching, i've noticed, that people recommend using DownloadDataAsync, instead of manually managing thread pool and using DownloadData

Comment: I'll say it again, you understand neither the Windows 7/8 TCP stack (which limits concurrent half-open connections to exactly 20) nor the thread pool (which limits your active thread count to the number of (virtual) cores = 4 or 8 most likely). And what I don't understand is why you bothered to ask if you argue every answer.

Comment: And because of the fact that you're underfeeding threads to your process, you're also missing another important piece of the HTTP stack: once you request too many files from modern, properly configured web servers you'll get dropped connections which you need to handle too. As to your other question, `openedconnections` could be protected by `lock()`, or you could use proper interlocked, lock-free synchonization (`Interlocked.Increment`/`Interlocked.Decrement`).

Comment: yeah, i know about too many requests. thanks for all your attention. i'll accept your answer, tho i don't completely agree =P